# swig error c++ for python director use

Tags: python, c++, swig

When building a `tool:crfsuite`, I got an error from `swig` on C++ when building a Python module:

```
swig -c++ -python -I../../include -o export_wrap.cpp export.i
```

Output:

```
/usr/share/swig/3.0.0/std/std_vector.i:87: Error: Can't copy typemap (directorout) std::vector< CRFSuite::Item,std::allocator< CRFSuite::Item > > = std::vector< CRFSuite::Item,std::allocator< CRFSuite::Item > > &DIRECTOROUT
/usr/share/swig/3.0.0/std/std_vector.i:87: Error: Can't copy typemap (in) std::vector< CRFSuite::Item,std::allocator< CRFSuite::Item > > *INPUT = std::vector< CRFSuite::Item,std::allocator< CRFSuite::Item > > *INOUT
/usr/share/swig/3.0.0/std/std_vector.i:87: Error: Can't copy typemap (in) std::vector< CRFSuite::Item,std::allocator< CRFSuite::Item > > &INPUT = std::vector< CRFSuite::Item,std::allocator< CRFSuite::Item > > &INOUT
/usr/share/swig/3.0.0/std/std_vector.i:87: Error: Can't copy typemap (typecheck) std::vector< CRFSuite::Item,std::allocator< CRFSuite::Item > > *INPUT = std::vector< CRFSuite::Item,std::allocator< CRFSuite::Item > > *INOUT
/usr/share/swig/3.0.0/std/std_vector.i:87: Error: Can't copy typemap (typecheck) std::vector< CRFSuite::Item,std::allocator< CRFSuite::Item > > &INPUT = std::vector< CRFSuite::Item,std::allocator< CRFSuite::Item > > &INOUT
/usr/share/swig/3.0.0/std/std_vector.i:87: Error: Can't copy typemap (argout) std::vector< CRFSuite::Item,std::allocator< CRFSuite::Item > > *OUTPUT = std::vector< CRFSuite::Item,std::allocator< CRFSuite::Item > > *INOUT
/usr/share/swig/3.0.0/std/std_vector.i:87: Error: Can't copy typemap (argout) std::vector< CRFSuite::Item,std::allocator< CRFSuite::Item > > &OUTPUT = std::vector< CRFSuite::Item,std::allocator< CRFSuite::Item > > &INOUT
/usr/share/swig/3.0.0/std/std_vector.i:87: Error: Can't copy typemap (typecheck) std::vector< CRFSuite::Item,std::allocator< CRFSuite::Item > > *INPUT = std::vector< CRFSuite::Item,std::allocator< CRFSuite::Item > > *INOUT
/usr/share/swig/3.0.0/std/std_vector.i:87: Error: Can't copy typemap (typecheck) std::vector< CRFSuite::Item,std::allocator< CRFSuite::Item > > &INPUT = std::vector< CRFSuite::Item,std::allocator< CRFSuite::Item > > &INOUT
/usr/share/swig/3.0.0/std/std_vector.i:87: Error: Can't copy typemap (freearg) std::vector< CRFSuite::Item,std::allocator< CRFSuite::Item > > *INPUT = std::vector< CRFSuite::Item,std::allocator< CRFSuite::Item > > *INOUT
/usr/share/swig/3.0.0/std/std_vector.i:87: Error: Can't copy typemap (freearg) std::vector< CRFSuite::Item,std::allocator< CRFSuite::Item > > &INPUT = std::vector< CRFSuite::Item,std::allocator< CRFSuite::Item > > &INOUT
```

The `.i` file seems simple:

```
%module(directors="1") crfsuite
%{
#include "crfsuite_api.hpp"
%}

%include "std_string.i"
%include "std_vector.i"
%include "exception.i"

%template(Item) std::vector<CRFSuite::Attribute>;
%template(ItemSequence) std::vector<CRFSuite::Item>;
%template(StringList) std::vector<std::string>;

%feature("director") Trainer;

%exception {
    try {
        $action
    } catch(const std::invalid_argument& e) {
        SWIG_exception(SWIG_IOError, e.what());
    } catch(const std::runtime_error& e) {
        SWIG_exception(SWIG_RuntimeError, e.what());
    } catch (const std::exception& e) {
        SWIG_exception(SWIG_RuntimeError, e.what());
    } catch(...) {
        SWIG_exception(SWIG_RuntimeError,"Unknown exception");
    }
}

%include "crfsuite_api.hpp"
```

Answer (score 5):

Try moving the `%include "crfsuite_api.hpp"` to before the first `%template` line.

Comment: bingo! i wonder about the detail,  why use comment "#" before.